# How to read config file key in SQL Server 2008 stored procedure 

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a settings.config file in my `c://config`

`settings.config` has this contents:

```
<filelocation>d://mydata</filelocation>
```

Now I want to get `d://mydata` file path in my SQL Server 2008 stored procedure, which will take this location as input for file creation path.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Can you guarantee the account sql server service is running as, has access to the file and or it is allowed to use xp_cmdshell?. Easiest way to do this get wahtever manages this config file to insert into some config table in the database.

Comment: Would agree with Tony. If really you don't have a choice, another option is to use a CLR stored proc to access your config file. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Simplified example but you could do something like this (assuming you can read the file from SQL Server):

```
declare @table table (Value XML)

insert @table
select a.* from openrowset (bulk 'C:\config', single_clob) a

select * from @table

select Value.value('filelocation[1]', 'varchar(100)')
from @table
```

Extend based on structure of your file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Aye assuming you can read it, more to the point assuming that will stay true. Only takes some one/ something to mess with the permissions on the file, and it all goes nipples up, locking wahtever manages the file to stop that happeng is about 500 times more effort than just querying the value into a tabel the db can see. Have a plus though.