# How to read certain values from .config file based on a particular value

Tags: xml, t-sql, config, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to insert a certain value into a SQL Server table from a .config file based on a particular key.

The simplified .config file looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="supportingLocalReview" value="true" />
    <add key="localFilingReviewServiceProxyAddress" value="http://web.myflcourtaccess.com:25500/SoapOutgoingRouter.svc/SecureMtom" />
    <add key="addReceivedStamp" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding />
    </bindings>
    <behaviors />
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://fca.com:155/RecordMDE/RecordMDE.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IntranetMtom" contract="Oasis.LegalXml.CourtFiling" name="RecordMDEServiceNew" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My initial process came from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761075/how-to-read-config-file-key-in-sql-server-2008-stored-procedure) in which I create a table and insert the entire file into the table using OPENROWSET:

```
INSERT @ConfigTable
       SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\Directory\Configuration\Broward_CMS_Interface_1.config', SINGLE_CLOB ) a

SELECT * FROM @ConfigTable;
```

And what I would like to insert into the configuration table is the endpoint address "http://fca.com:155/RecordMDE/RecordMDE.svc" if the `key="supportingLocalReview" value="true"` but I am unsure how I would accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read an XML file this way, you'll not *create a table*... You just read an XML *as is*. I suppose your variable ´@ConfigTable´ is declared as table and allows to insert XML in a column.

Therefore your `SELECT * FROM @ConfigTable` will return your XML - but not a table...

I saved your XML into a file on my local disk

This code returns the value of the `supportingLocalReview` and the `endpoint address`:

```
WITH MyConfigFile(AsXML) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'f:\test.xml', SINGLE_CLOB ) a
)
SELECT A.B.value('(appSettings/add[@key="supportingLocalReview"]/@value)[1]','bit') AS supportingLocalReview
      ,A.B.value('(system.serviceModel/client/endpoint/@address)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS endPointAddress
FROM MyConfigFile 
CROSS APPLY MyConfigFile.AsXML.nodes('configuration') AS A(B)
```

It should be easy to get other values into table-wise result set following this template...

What ever you want to do with these values should be no problem then...

Comment: Thank you - that works nicely.  Will probably be posting a follow-up question dealing with if the LocalReview = False to read another URL and hopefully you might be able to chime in!